# What advantages are gained by use of the phrase “further or alternatively”?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms

In legal fillings wherein a side’s legal argument or reasoning is laid out, one often finds the phrase “further or alternatively” delineating separate arguments. How would one’s position be different if one instead in these places simply said “furthermore”?

I suppose that the idea may be to ensure that the second leg of one’s reasoning is still considered, even if the first is found to fail. But having read many written judgments, I don’t think I’ve ever come across one where a judge doesn’t explicitly address each piece of a party’s reasoning, even if it’s to explain why they don’t need to fully consider it because another aspect of the case has rendered it moot.

What advantages then does one gain by use of the phrase “further or alternatively” instead of “furthermore”? I can see the disadvantage that it seems to nearly invite the possibility of the first leg of reasoning failing, and impress an almost sleazy sort of attitude like “these are my principles; if you don’t like them, I have others,” rather than believing fully in all the arguments of one’s submissions.

Answer (score 0):

### None

Choice of linking words in stating a case is pretty much a matter of style and is largely irrelevant to the outcome. If you prefer "Furthermore" rather than "further or alternatively", you do you.

### Alternative positions

I don't know what sort of judgements you are reading but alternative positions are extremely common and are always dealt with in the judgement - if only be saying "because I decided X, it is not necessary to consider Y".

The comparison to principles is unfair, and not just because lawyers don't have them. One of the things that the court will decide from confusing and often conflicting evidence is "what happened?" Because the parties don't know how the court will decide that rather fundamental question, they have to deal with all possible answers: was the porridge too hot, too cold, or just right? If too hot then I win because [reasons why I win if it's too hot], if too cold then I win because [reasons why I win if it's too cold], and if just right then I win because [reasons why I win if it's just right].

Many of these arguments will fall away as the case unfolds and, in a well-managed case, the court may issue decisions on particular matters (often at the request of the parties) to save everyone time by not having to deal with hypotheticals. For example, in commercial building cases, it's usual to resolve matters of entitlement before any work is done on matters of value - if you aren't entitled to it, who cares what it's worth?

Answer (score 0):

"Further" just informs the court that you are moving onto your next point. If you prefer "Furthermore", as DaleM suggests, "you do you."

"Alternatively", however, does add something. It informs that court that you are not necessarily claiming that your next point is logically consistent with your current point.

Generally speaking, in common law countries at least, you are allowed to arguing in the alternative. It is acceptable to argue, for example, that:

> If the Court finds that X is true, then we win for this reason, but if
> the Court finds that X is not true, then we win for that reason.